# svn checkout error

Tags: svn, svn-checkout

I'm trying to checkout a project from a remote repository. I'm on linux and I have connected through ssh

I'm trying to execute the following command

first I tried

```
svn co svn:://<ip address>/<repo path>
```

and it says

*svn: Client error in parsing arguments*

```
svn co svn:://<ip address>/<repo path> .
```

and it says (Please not the . I added at the end of the line)

*svn: 'svn:://' does not appear to be a URL*

I'm sure the path is correct

Does any one could help me

thanks in advance

Comment: Doesn't the error message tell you exactly what is wrong?? `svn: 'svn:://' does not appear to be a URL`

Answer (score 3):

Change it to:

```
svn co svn://<ip address>/<repo path> .
```

You have an error - there is no double colons there. You have http://, https://, ftp:// and svn://. All of them use single colon.